# Does there exist a closed form for the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{tn}}{n^2}$ where $t<0$.?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Does there exist a closed form for the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{tn}}{n^2}$ where $t<0$.?

I was trying to form an arithmetico-geometric progression but ended futile.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html

Comment: Oh so _that's_ what it's called.  The reference is as good as any answer I would have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is known as the [dilogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html), also known as [Spence's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function). There are many different representations given on the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Particular_values), and various identities are shown on [the same page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm).

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(e^t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{nt}}{n^2}$$